# access a variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code.

```
var Outside = "Test";
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Tests",
        CAMLViewFields: ViewFields,
        completefunc: function (xData, status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                var Project = Outside;
            })
        }
    });
```

How i must cange to use the variable "Outside" in the function? 
In my code the variable "Outside" is in the Funktion null.

Thanks for your Help

Stefan

Comment: it shouldn't be null, can you show a fiddle of this? is this exactly how it is in your code or is Outside under a different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I see attemp to work with Sharepoint. :) I am SP dev too, I tried your code and I received "null" too...

But when I tried this:

```
window.Outside = "Test"
```

It works well. Of course it can't be in another function! It must be defined as global scope.